# why i see white page when upload my php on my host?

Tags: php, wamp, host

I designed my site with php and it works fine on wamp server,but when i uploaded my PHP site to my host and i went to my site address i saw only white page.(it show only page title in correct way!)
I used some include sentence with pointing to parent directory with using two point "../"
Do you think that this can be cuse of problem?
Please recommend me a way to find error and debug it.
This is my first page code:(i should mention that for example when i go to content.php it display correct)

```
<?php
include("includes/classes/mysession.php");
$ms=new Mysession("turkish_az","home");
$ms->setCurrentPage("home"); 
if(isset($_GET["slc_language"])){
$ms->setLanguage($_GET["slc_language"]);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="includes/css/style_header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="includes/css/style_home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="includes/css/syle_footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#slc_language").val("<?php echo($ms->getLanguage());?>");
$("#form_search").submit(function(e) {
    var data=$(this).serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pages/meaning/mean.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(resp){
        $("#resultpart").html(resp);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<?php require("pages/header/header.php"); ?>
<?php require("pages/main/content.php"); ?>
<?php require("pages/footer/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i checked hedear & content & footer php files:
1-The header show white page like first page
2-The content is show correct
3-the footer show half correct but has an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getLayoutName() on a non-object in /home/u998326115/public_html/pages/footer/footer.php on line 14
```

Comment: On your host, check for a file called 'error_log'. If it exists, download it and see what the last line says.

Comment: I think there are some error in your code, and error reporting or display errors turned off. add `error_reporting('E_ALL');` and `display_errors(1);` at the top of your file.

Comment: @GaryLuck->I searched for it,it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have two bits of php, some above the title and some below.

Since you are getting the page title, we can conclude it's the lower php which causes the page to not load.

Presumably the paths to the files you're including are not right. Try changing the very first "include" to "require", do you now stop getting the title? In which case your paths are wrong.

Add this to the very top

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: I changed first include to require and the title is working,there isn't any error but it don't add header.php and content.php and footer.php when i save the page in html format,i see that content of budy tag is empty.I added that two line to top of my php code and still no error exist!

Comment: It is true there was a problem in first include i changed my database address in session class and it works now,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Find in your hosting docs how you can see error logs. It can be file error_log in script folders, some files in folder logs or you can access to logs in hosting control panel (CPanel, for example). Or you can ask your hosting support.
2. Turn on error display and set error level to E_ALL for all your scripts. You can make this in .htaccess file or in your code. Ask your hosting support team how you can make this better.

Comment: I went to error logs in files part and it write Nothing to show!I added error_reporting('E_ALL'); and it didn't change.